# Pymunk multi-core collision resolution?

Tags: game-physics, physics-engine, chipmunk, pymunk

I have a very basic space set up with a large number (10000) of circles falling under gravity. It seems that only one of my cores is active at all at any point in time, but as far as I know collision resolution is extremely parallelizable with space partitioning, which the Chipmunk engine does indeed implement.

It seems that even when I create the space with `threaded=True` on Linux, and `space.use_spatial_hash()`, the issue persists. I really need the extra performance parallel threads could provide, what are my options? Should I move to pybullet instead with planar constraints to emulate 2d?

[image]

Comment: It would be very interesting with a benchmark comparing pymunk and pybullet. If you do something small and self contained, I would be very happy if you could share it, for example by writing a issue on the pymunk github repo at https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/issues (I might make one myself, but looks quite complicated)

Comment: @viblo thanks for the interest but I am not nearly familiar enough with either pymunk or pybullet to write 1:1 scenarios. Since you are the author of the library, is what I am experiencing expected behaviour? Is this another case of GIL crippling threadable logic? From what I understand being non-Windows is the only requirement for using threading here, but my cpu doesn't see my code any different with threaded=True. Thank you.

Comment: Yes this is expected, I updated my answer below. It does not have anything to with Python, but the threading implementation in Chipmunk, the underlying C library that does the physics calculations. It is fairly limited, and I think it was mainly implemented to speed up execution on mobiles.

Comment: Regarding pybullet, my very uninformed guess is that pybullet will be slower than pymunk unless its configured to use GPU and/or a 2d solver (but Im not sure if that is possible/easy from pybullet, or if its only in bullet). If using GPU and/or a 2d solver then I dont know, pybullet could very well be faster in those cases. I looked some more at how to create a pybullet comparison, but it was quite complicated compared to pymunk. I lost motivation when I couldnt figure out how to set it to use 2d solver which according to the bullet docs should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the number of thread to use as well, for example like `your_space.threads = 2`

In the docs its written like this ([Space.**init**](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.Space.__init__)):

> If you set threaded=True the step function will run in threaded mode which might give a speedup. Note that even when you set threaded=True you still have to set Space.threads=2 to actually use more than one thread.

You can verify that it works by running the threaded_space example `python -m pymunk.examples.threaded_space`. If I do that and watch CPU usage in `htop` I can easily see when it goes from 1 to 2 threads.

I should also add that unfortunately the multi-threading does not improve performance much in most cases. It can only help if there's a lot of collisions going on at the same time, but even then its not much (Maybe on ARM it gives bigger improvement, but that I cannot try).

Comment: Thank you for the response. This does not seem to be making a difference. I have tried both this and the hidden _set_threads() method to the same effect. I have updated my question with the cpu core utilization graph.